# How to calculate obtuse angle between two vectors?

Tags: math

How to calculate obtuse angle between two vectors if both vectors and x axis is given.
First vector can be taken as x axis. we can get acute by dot product and acos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before applying acos, check if the dot product is negative. If negative, the angle is obtuse :)

Further, as acos has a range of 0 to pi, you will do fine as long as you do not want reflex angles (>pi)

Comment: Sorry, But I could not able to get full angles... I have list of points and two external point (one is origin and second is on x). I should get 0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360 in case of 9 points on circle

Comment: Assuming your known points are origin O (0,0), vector1 head A (x,0) - on the x-axis and another point B (m,n). If you want the angle made by OA and OB, the angle would be acos(m/sqrt(m*m + n*n))*180/pi degrees.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use both dot and cross products to correctly resolve the angle.
Angle between vectors u and v is

```
||atan2(s,c)||
where `s = ||u X v||`  (magnitude of the cross product)
and `c = u.v`        (dot product)
```

and `atan2` is the 4-quadrant inverse tan function

and `||*||` denotes magnitude (norm).

This will always return an angle between 0 and 180 degrees.